# Get the information from Dictionary with reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dictionary

Let's say I have a class with the following schema.

```
public MyClass {
    public Dictionary<String, Class1> Dict1 { get; set; }

    public Myclass() {
       // Add and work with dic1
    }
}
```

I'd like to use reflection to get all class1 of the dict1. I hope this is clear, otherwise let me know and I will put additional information. Thanks, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use reflection; why does `Dict1.Values` not suffice?

Comment: I in MyClass i have few more Dictionaries, and is dynamic. Which means I don't know anything about class1, class2 etc. so I thought I will get all properties of Myclass by GetType().GetProperties() then loop in dictionary to get values of each keys. Thanks for your reply. I can change the design if there is better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
dic1.Values.OfType<Class1>()
```

Comment: Actually, Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values are already an ICollection<TValue>, no need to call .OfType<T>().